# Some basic Mathematical proofs on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

After a long time passed from graduation we were recently discussing some matters with my colleagues when one asked me to prove that

> $ A \cap A = A $
>
> $A \cup A = A$
>
> $\neg (\neg A) = A$

I came up with [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Intersection) site which gives a brief theory of set intersection, but can not proceed any further on my examples.

We know that these are all true but can not prove them theoretically. Made some Google search but all ended up with some set theory of which give the basic but not a proof.

Can anybody with a knowledge on the subject help me to prove these?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formal logic will sound almost silly, but we show that they are subsets of each other.  For example (setting aside the trivial empty set case), suppose $x\in A\cap A$.  Then $x\in A$ and $x\in A$.  Thus, $x\in A$.  Therefore, $A\cap A\subseteq A$.
Now suppose $x\in A$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in A$.  Thus, $x\in A\cap A$.  Therefore, $A\subseteq A\cap A$. Therefore, $A\cap A = A$.  And similar arguments apply for the other two.

Comment: That was very good approach and a nice solution. Thank you very much.